# My dropDownButton stoped working Flutter app

Tags: flutter

I have a dropdownbutton in my flutter app that I'm trying to populate with a function that retrieves a list with a result from a SQLite query.

I can't understand why the dropdown button is not working, I can't press it at all.

I had the same code working just yesterday and the dropdown button worked but now it is not working.

Here is the dropdown button:

```
FutureBuilder<List<Utilizador>>(
                    future: user.getUtilizadores(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                        AsyncSnapshot<List<Utilizador>> snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
                      return DropdownButton<Utilizador>(
                          items: snapshot.data?.map((util) => DropdownMenuItem<Utilizador>(
                            child: Text(util.nome),
                            value: util,
                          )).toList(),
                          onChanged: (Utilizador? val) {
                            setState(() {
                              _currentUser = val;
                            });
                          },
                        isExpanded: false,
                        hint: Text("Utilizadores")
                      );
                    }
                  )
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the debug console?

Comment: nope, i dont get any erros

Comment: Can you please open your SQLite DB with SQLite DB Browser which is a graphical user interface and check what data is stored there? Could it be that you had not really saved the data in the DB?